# How to implement Android onboarding quickstart?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am looking to implement [this type](https://material.google.com/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-quickstart) of onboarding guide for my app's floating action button. Are there predefined templates or example code that explain how to implement this feature? I couldn't find any examples of code for this, only Material Design Do/Don't Do...

EDIT: this is a picture of the onboarding guide.

[image: Floating Action Button ONBOARDING GUIDE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there aren't any official templates or code snippets that explain this Material Design Guideline however - like with everything else in the Android world - there's an unofficial open-source library called [MaterialTapTargetPromo](https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt) for this which does exactly what you're looking for.

You can check out the [Sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.samuelwall.materialtaptargetprompt.sample) as well.

Answer (score -3):

There are already templates in Android Studio.

Open Android Studio and select `File` > `New` > `Activity` > `Basic Activity`.

Then, modify any things you needed. Click `Finish` and you can read the template.

Comment: I appreciate an answer but did you read the question? I know how to create a new activity....

Comment: @PengWins Correct me if I am wrong. You said " Are there predefined templates or example code that explain how to implement this feature". `Basic Activity` has included some of the Lollipop new features **including** floating action button.

Comment: the link points to the onboarding for floating action button. Not the action button code. Question updated to be absolutely clear.

Comment: If you mean the background, I think you can do it by images.